# MQ Explorer - How to start default listener ( like SYSTEM.DEFAULT.LISTENER.TCP)?

Tags: ibm-mq

How to start default listener (like `SYSTEM.DEFAULT.LISTENER.TCP`) from MQ Explorer?
Should be possible, right? - Just like you can start a queue manager in Explorer.
If there is, can someone tell me how explicitly?

I know how to do it outside of Explorer using the MQSC command:

```
START LISTENER('SYSTEM.DEFAULT.LISTENER.TCP')
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your MQ Explorer list of listeners is showing system objects (one of the icons in the top right), then right click on the listener object that you want to start and choose Start from the context menu.

[image: MQ Explorer Listener List showing Context menu to start listener]

Comment: Hi Morag, I tried selecting Listeners under the Queue Manager as in your pic, but the right side pane contain no listeners at all to select! Any idea why? Using version 9.3.1.0

Comment: Hi @JImG. Have you made sure that you are showing system objects?